# Converting unicode string into usable unicode in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a database of Unicode strings for emoji such as `U0001F60A`. I want to pull them from the database and convert them into actual usable unicode strings. (So they appear as emoji and not a bunch of characters.) The standard form seems to be `u'\U0001F60A'`, however, I cannot get this form.

```
if sentiment < 0:
    emoji = cursor.execute("SELECT emojiuni FROM emojineg WHERE id='{}';".format(num)) # Get negative emoji from DB.
    emoji = cursor.fetchone()
    emoji = emoji[0]
```

This makes `emoji = U0001F60A` but I can't append it to `u'\` trying variations like

```
`"u'\" + emoji + "'"`
u' + "\" + emoji + "'"
u'\emoji
```

Don't work, because `u'` seems to be a protected command. Is there a way to make the strings into unicode characters, along the lines of the `encode()` command? (I've tried that also, but that doesn't seem to work, but maybe I'm not doing it right.) Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I cannot for the life of me get this form"* - Less, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.x:

```
>>> print unichr(int('U0001F60A'[1:], 16))
```

3.x:

```
>>> print(chr(int('U0001F60A'[1:], 16)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly.

Comment: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode character '\U0001f60a' in position 0: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk` ??

Comment: @frederick99: Yup. Tk is terrible that way.

Comment: Wait. I'm on python 3!

Comment: @frederick99: ah, [How to print non-BMP Unicode characters in Tkinter (e.g. )](//stackoverflow.com/q/23530080) then. There are a [series of bugs open on IDLE and non-BMP codepoints](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp#q=idle+non-bmp+site:bugs.python.org).

Comment: This is not related to the question or the answer. Why does `print('ab\b')` print `ab*` in IDLE instead of just `a`? (`*`:a square character)

Comment: @frederick99: Because `"\b"` is a single non-printable character, but Tk interprets it differently than the terminal.